# Only allow certain blocks to be broken with mining fatigue

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to make sure players cant break any blocks but wheat, while they have the mining fatigue effect. Is there a way to detect if they are trying to break the wheat or is there a way to only allow wheat?

Comment: You could try giving him a tool that allows him to break wheat while he has Mining Fatigue, and then remove that tool when Mining Fatigue is removed. (Presuming the player is in Adventure Mode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Detecting if a player is breaking wheat is (as far as i know) **not** possible.
*However* if you only want people to be able to break wheat, you first have to put everyone into adventure mode with:

```
/gamemode 2 @a
```

Now, no one can break blocks anymore. Give the people you want to be able to break wheat a tool you can obtain by typing:

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_hoe 1 0 {CanDestroy:["minecraft:wheat"]}
```

That will give you a diamond hoe that is able to break wheat. If you want a different tool just replace `diamond_hoe` with a different item name. You can find those item names in the [minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Shears) by looking into the box on the right.

Comment: This only works in 1.8 and above

Comment: 1.13 syntax for first command: `/gamemode adventure @a`

Comment: 1.13 syntax for second command `/give @p minecraft:diamond_hoe{CanDestroy:["minecraft:wheat"]}`